# Whats the fastest way of do a checking and drop of two asymetrical dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have two dataframes. Dataframe A (named data2_) has 2,5 million rows and 15 columns, Dataframe B (named data) has 250 rows and 4 columns. Both have a matching column: IDENTITY.

I want to reduce Dataframe A to just the rows who match with the IDENTITY row of Dataframe B.

I tried that, but takes a lot to compute (tqdm estimates a year):

```
for i in tqdm(list(range(data2_.shape[0]))):
    for t in list(range(data.shape[0])):
        if data2_["IDENTITY"].iloc[i] != data["IDENTITY"].iloc[t]:
            data2_.drop( index = i)
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: `data2_[data2_['IDENTITY'].isin(data['IDENTITY'])]` ..?